# vscode on linux, intellisense installed and enabled, but not working

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm just trying vscode one more time after a year or so. I'm using it for web development so really want the html snippets to be working, but none of it is, I don't get any suggestions, and typing ctrl-space brings up a box telling me there are no suggestions. What do I need to do to get this to work. It's a completely fresh install on a freshly installed Linux Mint20. I always thought this part worked out of the box, it did 2 or three years ago when it was using it on a mac, I expected a similar behaviour to be honest. do I have to enable another setting to allow intellisense to work. I've no idea, it works out of the box on a mac.

Comment: is it showing any errors?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution after 5 hours, it's at the bottom right of the screen, file type should be "HTML" or whatever file it should be, not just "plain text". Vscode will pick this up from the file extension, but for testing, I just clicked file - new file, which of course will be plain text by default.

Feel like a bit of an idiot, but hopefully this will save someone else trying to fix this.